# Live reload not working in Spring boot devtools

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using this dependency in a spring boot application:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-devtools-restart-exclude) says:

> By default, changing resources in /META-INF/maven,
>   /META-INF/resources, /resources, **/static**, /public, or /templates does
>   not trigger a restart but **does trigger a live reload**.

The [live reload documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-devtools-livereload) says:

> The spring-boot-devtools module includes an embedded LiveReload server
>   that can be used to trigger a browser refresh when a resource is
>   changed. LiveReload browser extensions are freely available for
>   Chrome, Firefox and Safari from livereload.com.

Now, I am using Maven and my static folder is under src/main/resources, so my folder structure is:

src/main/resources/static/index.html

This is what's in my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>HI THERE! Get your greeting <a href="/greeting">here</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I using chrome browser but am not using any live reload browser extension in chrome.

I run the application with this Powershell command (since I'm using spring boot maven plugin):

```
mvn clean package; java -jar target\project-name-version.jar
```

This starts up the server on localhost:8080 and displays the contents of index.html in a web page.

However, when I then make changes to index.html in Eclipse IDE and save the file, and I then refresh the browser page, **I do not see the new changes.**

How come live reload isn't working for me? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Running the application from the IDE is not a constraint to make Developer tools working.
Your problem is somewhere else.

These commands :

```
mvn clean package; 
java -jar target\project-name-version.jar
```

mean that you don't use the spring-boot maven plugin to run your application.
You run the autobootable jar of your fully packaged application.
Consequently, Spring Boot devtools are disabled as stated by the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools) :

> **Developer tools are automatically disabled when running a fully
>   packaged application**. If your application is launched from java -jar
>   or if it is started from a special classloader, then it is considered
>   a “production application”. Flagging the dependency as optional is a
>   best practice that prevents devtools from being transitively applied
>   to other modules that use your project. Gradle does not support
>   optional dependencies out-of-the-box, so you may want to have a look
>   at the propdeps-plugin.

To run the application from command line in exploded/dev mode, `mvn clean package` is not required and helpless.
Just execute `mvn spring-boot:run`

Comment: Good answer. It's also important to note that you also have to "build project" (not maven install) in the IDE to trigger a restart.

Comment: do you mean use the `mvn install` command on maven? and `gradle build` command on gradle, in second terminal or command prompt? It is very complicated if you doing everything without an IDE, which is not building your application on save. you probably setup a gulp task using nodejs to watch files and build on changes.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by below approach -

- First open setting.json (ctrl + shift+P) file and define a property there as "java.autobuild.enabled": true.
- second open application.properties file and define a property as spring.devtools.restart.pollInterval=10s

Hope it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Set Build project automatically.
In intellij  File –> Setting –> Build, Execution, Deployment –> Compiler –> check the Build project automatically
In eclipse  Window -> Preferences -> Workspace -> General -> Build -> Check ‘build automatically’